Захотелось разнообразия (?) и вот я тут (?) в Москве
Нужно ли тире перед "и" и перед "в Москве" какой знак препинания? Скажите, пожалуйста.

Правильно:
Захотелось разнообразия — и вот я тут, в Москве.
Пояснение
Тире ставится в ССП перед союзом И для обозначения увеличенной паузы.
Это неосновной знак, он связан с разной структурой простых предложений в составе ССП, а также обозначает резкий переход.
В Москве — уточняющее обстоятельство после местоимения тут (где именно?), обособление запятой.

Точно так же хотел расставить знаки, а потом увидел уже ваш ответ. ;)

Мы с вами одинаково слышим  нашу речь. Я тоже не задумываясь выбрала этот вариант.
